# Using band threshold to modify value of another band in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I've recently been working on MODIS' ice product, and I want to use whether the value of the band by class is equal to some specific value to determine whether the band by NDSI is 0 or 1.codes as follows:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2002-02-24', '2010-02-26'));
//var image = dataset.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
//define a threshold
function upperImg(image){
  var band=image.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
  return image.where(band.gte(10),1)
}
function lowerImg(image){
  var band=image.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
  return image.where(band.lt(10),0)
}
function inlandwater(image){
  var a=image.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
  var b=image.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover_Class')
  return image.
}
var fsnow = dataset.map(lowerImg);
var filtsnow = fsnow.map(upperImg);
var snowCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 2400.0,
  palette: ['black', '0dffff', '0524ff', 'ffffff'],
};
var qzgy=ee.FeatureCollection(table);
function clipImg(image){
  return image.clipToCollection(qzgy);
}
var clipCol= filtsnow.map(clipImg);
var sum = clipCol.sum();
Map.centerObject(qzgy);

var snow =sum.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
//var snow =clipCol.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
Map.addLayer(snow,snowCoverVis,"snowcover");
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you would like to achieve. Can you try and expand the question a bit or give an example?

Comment: I want to use a pixel with a band value of ndsi class equal to 237 or 201 to make the value of this image element in the NDSI band 0